# Why does C++ template function not recognize a function in the same header file

Tags: c++, templates

This is probably a question that goes back to a fundamental understanding of how C++ compile a program.  I have the following set of functions defined in a `.hpp` file.  The line `keys = get_keys(inputs)` is causing the problem.  The compiler gives me the following error message `Use of undeclared identifier 'get_keys'`.  However, `get_keys()` is defined right below it.  I tried implementing the `get_keys` function in the `.cpp` file and just declaring the prototype in the `.hpp` file since it is not a template function, but that did not work either.  Why can I not access this function?

```
template <typename ...Funcs>
static std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>>
ode_solver(double step_size, double start, double stop, double error,
           std::string func_name, std::map<std::string, double> &inputs,
           Funcs&&... funcs)
{

    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    // THE COMPILER DOES NOT RECOGNIZE get_keys in the below line
    keys = get_keys(inputs);
    std::vector<double> one = {0.0, 1.0};
    std::vector<double> two = {0.0, 1.0};
    std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> three(one, two);
    return three;
}
// ================================================================

std::vector<std::string>
get_keys(std::map<std::string, double> & arr)
{
    std::vector<std::string> keys;
    for (typename std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it = arr.begin();
         it != arr.end(); it++)
    {
        keys.push_back(it -> first);
    }
    return keys;
}
// ================================================================
```

Comment: A function has to be declared before it can be used. So you need to add the declaration of `get_keys` before the definition of `ode_solver`.

Comment: Everything must be declared before it can be used (except for some situations inside a class definition).

Comment: @aschepler: There is also dependent ADL which can see later declarations, but it doesn’t apply here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, `get_keys()` is defined right below it.

There's your problem.   You are expecting something that isn't so.

As a rough rule of thumb, the compiler needs everything (types, names) to be declared BEFORE they are used.

Practically, that means the declaration needs to be above (if in the same source file),  or declared in a header file that is `#include`d above the point of use.

Note this is a rule of thumb, because there are a few exceptions (e.g. an inline member function of a class can use a data member of that class, even if the declaration of that member is below it within the class definition).   Your example is not one of those exceptions.

You either need to declare `get_keys()` before the point of use, or move the definition (which is a type of declaration) to so it is before the point of use.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned either add a declaration of `get_keys`:

```
std::vector<std::string>
get_keys(std::map<std::string, double> &);
```

Before definition of `ode_solver`, to be recognized first.
Or simply swap their place since `get_keys` does not use `ode_solver`.